# ¿como resuelvo un conflicto en git al momento de subir a github?

Tags: git

Estos son los pasos que hice:

```
git clone "https://github.com/dixroby/codigoNuevo"
```

Después  generé un conflicto editando una linea de código y al momento de subir

```
git add . 
git commit -m "subiendo conflicto"
git push
```

pues me aparece un error error: `failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/dixroby/codigoNuevo.git'`

seguidamente yo hago un

```
git pull
```

y nuevamente un

```
git push
```

y el problema se soluciona

La pregunta es ¿los pasos que muestro son los correctos?  Por lo que sé es que tengo que solucionar ese conflicto eligiendo el original o la nueva modificación.

> ¿Es la forma correcta  de solucionar un conflicto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un `git push` sólo puede fallarte si alguien ha modificado la copia en Githhub antes de tu `push` (bien porque ha editado "online" algo, o bien porque ha hecho a su vez un push, antes que el tuyo). En ese se rechaza el push porque tu copia local del repositorio no está actualizada. Todavía no es un conflicto realmente, sino un mero aviso de que no estás actualizado.

Debes hacer un pull para actualizarla. En ese momento puede generarse un conflicto si lo que bajas con pull "choca" con los cambios locales (has modificado localmente un fichero que también fue modificado en el push). Pero también puede ser que no haya conflicto alguno (porque los cambios remotos no chocan con los cambios locales), en cuyo caso git simplemente mezclará ambos cambios creando un nuevo commit con la mezcla.

Si en cambio hay conflictos, Git no puede completar la mezcla sin tu ayuda. Debes resolver el conflicto mirando los ficheros que han "chocado"  y dejándolos a tu gusto.

Git habrá introducido en esos ficheros unas marcas del estilo `<<<<<<` y `>>>>>>` para delimitar las líneas en conflicto. Entre ambas marcas aparecerá una línea de `======` para separar la versión que tenías localmente de la versión remota.

Debes leer con cuidado esas líneas, decidirte por una de las dos versiones (o hacer tú mismo un mix y crear una nueva) y eliminar todas esas marcas. Es decir, debes dejar ese fichero como querrías que quede en su versión final.

Una vez hecho eso harás un `git add` de ese fichero y `git commit` para completar el pull que había quedado "interrumpido" por el conflicto. Eso creará un nuevo commit local que guarda los cambios que has hecho durante la mezcla.

Tanto si hubo conflicto como si no, una vez completado el `pull` es conveniente que hagas un `git push` para que el repositorio remoto contenga también el commit "mezcla" (más los commits locales que aún no estaban en el remoto).

Comment: gracias por aclarar mi duda estoy muy agradecido

Comment: De nada. Si la respuesta es lo que buscabas, puedes marcarla como aceptada (pulsando en ✅)